# gcc - использование директив для отключения warning'ов

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Возможно, я необоснованно называю это "warning'ами" - для макроса

```
#define DEFINE_DERIVED_EXCEPTION(BASE, DERIVED) \
class DERIVED : public BASE { \
public: \
    explicit DERIVED(std::string_view ARG) \
        : BASE(ARG) \
    {} \
};
```

IDE выдает подсказку следующего содержания:

> Macro argument should be enclosed in parentheses.

Я не уверен, что не существует ключа, при котором бы это сообщение превратилось в *настоящий* warning от компилятора, и если такого нет - то вопрос можно считать закрытым. Если есть способ заставить компилятор ругаться на такие вещи - тогда можно ли их отключить с помощью конструкции  вроде этой:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "тут что-то должно быть"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

*Toolchains*: gcc-7

Comment: А компилятор *без IDE* (при запуске из командной строки) тоже выдает этот warning?

Comment: @avp, нет, не выдает. Но я написал об этом выше: я не уверен, что нет флага, при котором бы он выплюнул warning'и такого рода. Но, если его действительно нет - вопрос можно считать закрытым :)

Comment: Посмотрел на флаги для [GCC-7](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary), особенно флаги препроцессора, g++ и gcc и ничего адекватного таким проверкам макросов не увидел

Comment: @avp, спасибо, что потратили время. Буду знать)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы начал с того, что подавление предупреждений следует использовать только в крайнем случае, когда приходится иметь дело со сторонним кодом или какими-то проблемами в самом компиляторе. Здесь явно не такой случай. Далее, сам макрос выглядит откровенно ненужным. Может у вас в реальном коде он устроен как-то сложнее, но в таком виде его имхо стоит убрать и объявлять классы либо вручную, благо появилась поддержка наследование конструкторов, либо как шаблон с тегом.

```
class Derived: public Base {
   public: using Base::Base; // будут использоваться конструктор(ы) из Base
};

// вариант с шаблоном
enum class ExceptionCategory{ ... };

template<ExceptionCategory category>
class Derived: public Base {
   public: using Base::Base;
};

вместо класса с новым именем используем один и тот же шаблонный класс с разными параметрами
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По поводу Вашего комментария: данный макрос я разместил `как есть`, но есть аналогичные, которые действительно устроены сложнее. Возможно, мне стоило бы обобщить вопрос - как быть с аргументами макроса, которые используются нетривиальным, если так можно выразиться, способом? Т.е., это нечто отличное от ```#define min(X, Y)  ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))```. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @isnullxbh Ну так аргумент не всегда нужно оборачивать в скобки, а иногда макрос может от этого стать нерабочим.